# wbemcli Http Exception: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: authorize.net-cim, wbem

I am getting the above error on Ubuntu 14.04 on running this following command -

wbemcli ecn "http://:5988/root/cimv2"

Error - wbemcli Http Exception: Couldn't connect to server

In fact every wbemcli command is giving this error.

Any solution idea or thoughts to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an actual hostname, like this:

```
wbemcli ecn "http://localhost:5988/root/cimv2"
```

Also, you may need to authenticate.

For https, you would use (if you have the right certificates)

```
wbemcli ecn "https://localhost:5989/root/cimv2"
```